# Why does this method for solving equations with complex number roots not always work?

Tags: complex-numbers

Here's the question:

$1+3i$ is a root of the cubic $z^3+6z+20=0$. Identify the other two roots.

Obviously the conjugate complex number is another root so one is $1-3i$.

So I use the general formula $z^2-(\alpha+\beta)+\alpha\beta=0$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the complex conjugate pair, to work out that the cubic in question comes from, which I find to be:

$(z^2-z+10)(z+a)$, where $a$ is some number.

For the next part I set the cubic as $z^3+0z^2+6z+20=0$.

$\therefore$ $az^2-z^2=0z^2$

so $a=1$.

However, my problem arises when I try to find $a$ using the other powers:

With the same method,

$-za+10z=6z$

$\therefore a=4$

And with: $10a=20$, $a=2$.

Which value of $a$ is the correct one?

Surely I should get the same value for $a$ on each of these? Or am I making a silly error?

For varying questions of this nature, I've found that some work fine and some don't.

Comment: $(1+3i) +  (1-3i) = 2$.

Comment: It is actually more natural to guess by trial and error that $z=-2$ is a root and then invoke the factor theorem.

Comment: Given that $1\pm3i$ are zeros of the polynomial $p(z)$ one can perform long division $p(z):(z^2-2z+10)$ and will obtain a polynomial $p_1(z)$ of degree $2$ less.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Complex conjugate root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem), if $1+3i$ is a root. so will be $1-3i$

So, $z^3+6z+20=(z-a)\{z-(1+3i)\}\{z-(1-3i)\}=(z-a)(z^2-2z+10)$

as $\{z-(1+3i)\}\{z-(1-3i)\}=(z-1)^2-(-3i)^2=z^2-2z+1-(-9)=z^2-2z+10$

$z^3+6z+20=z^3-z^2(a+2)+z(2a+10)-10a$

Compare the coefficient any power (that involves $a$)  of $z$  to find $a=-2$