# Finding roots of $ z^4 - 1 = 0$ and $z^3 + 6z +20 = 0$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Using the fact that $|s|^2 = ss^*$ (where $s$ is a complex number, and $s^*$ it's conjugate) or other methods, how can I find the root of the following independent equations:

$$
z^4 - 1 = 0  \\
z^3 + 6z +20 = 0
$$

It would be nice if you could explain the general reasoning, as opposed to showing how it works in this particular example so that the SE community and I can tackle future problems like these.

Comment: You can see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247312/what-are-the-solutions-to-z41-0) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474940/why-does-this-method-for-solving-equations-with-complex-number-roots-not-always).

Comment: Are you looking to solve these equations simultaneously or independently?

Comment: Take care that Rohan's example in the first of his links is not quite the same, and discusses a slightly different issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is slightly unclear to me. However, the general method is the following:

We know how to find solutions of quadratic equations; using the quadratic formula. These are not quadratic equations, so lets try to reduce them to something of the form of a quadratic equation (or even simpler, if we're lucky).

$$0=z^4 - 1 = (z^2 - 1)(z^2 + 1)$$

We now have two factors, both of which are quadratic. We can use the quadratic formula on each of them in turn to find solutions.

In your second example,

$$z^3 + 6z + 20 = 0 $$

we have a little more trouble, as we can't see so clearly how to break this down into it's constituent factors. A good first step is to guess at some solutions. After a few tries, we figure out that

$z=-2$

is a solution. 
This corresponds to a factor of $(z+2)$. So we know, now, that

$$z^3 + 6z + 20 = (z+2)*B$$

Where B is the other factor. So what is B? Well, we need a thing which multiplies with the $(z+2)$ factor to give our original expression. You can do this any way you like to find out what B is, but I prefer the following:

$$z^3 + 6z + 20 = (z+2)*(z^2+kx+10)$$

Where $k$ is unknown. We know that we want the first and last terms to be $z^2$ and $10$, because they need to multiply to give $z^3$ and $20$, respectively, in the original expression.

Expand the left hand side out and find out what $k$ is. You then have a quadratic which you can solve, using the formula.

Comment: "After a few tries"... Hm, I think you should mention the rational roots theorem.

Comment: Well. Duly noted.